# Running SSIS Package Remotely with SSMS Fails, Why?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms, ssms-2012

Why running SSIS package locally on the server where MS SQL reside using SSMS works fine, but when I run the same SSIS package remotely on my pc using SSMS fails? The error message complains about the acquireconnection to connection manager failed.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the answer and the error was a bit misleading I have to say. I had converted from project deployment model to package deployment model previously and enable package configuration hoping to use configuration file. then I deployed the package to file system and ran the package remotely with ssms, which lead to the error message complaining about the acquireconnection method failed. Today, i had a hunch and converted the package back from package deployment model to project deployment model, then deployed and ran the package perfectly fine. I repeated it several times for sanity sake.